# Directory that contains files from many network directories

Tags: windows, cmd, directory

**Scenario:**

My organization has 7 application servers with exact copies of our software.

Each application copy logs are contained in a subdirectory for given software component. ie. Log\ServiceA\, Log\ServiceB\

So in total I have 7 Log\ServiceA\ directories with .logs in a different network locations.

**Question:**

Is there any way to create a virtual directory that contains all files contained in all 7 network locations? File names WILL be duplicated. Logging in the same network location is not a solution.

So far I have only managed to create directory that contains 7 network shortcuts to log folders.

Comment: Er, if there are files with identical file names, how should a hypothetical virtual folder discriminate them?

Comment: Use `MKLINK /?` to read about making links to other directories. Google for more information on the ramifications of creating links across a network.